# android constraint layout installation

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-constraintlayout

When I try to compile my project it tells me that i must install `Constraintlayout`.

However, when i come to install them, the installation fails.
there is the **output**:

> To install:
>   - Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2 (extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.2)
>   - ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.2 (extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2)
>   Preparing "Install Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2 (revision: 1)".
>   Failed to read or create install properties file.
>   Preparing "Install ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.2 (revision: 1)".
>   Failed to read or create install properties file.
>   Failed packages:
>   - Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2 (extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.2)
>   - ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.2 (extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2)

Comment: Could be a file read/write issue. Consider re-installing you Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

you should use android studio 2.2.+ and **add google maven repository** in app level gradle file

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

and add this dependencies in same file:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

please run android studio in ADMIN mode. and then click install on error log link to install ..." ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.2 (revision: 1)"

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting your **.AndroidStudio2.x** folder in your profile directory after taking a backup.